# Update where value pair matches in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, updates

I need to update this table:

Centers:

```
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  id |  country   | process | center |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  1  |     1      |    1    |   1    |
|  2  |     1      |    2    |   1    |
|  3  |     1      |    3    |   1    |
|  4  |     2      |    1    |   1    |
|  5  |     2      |    2    |   1    |
|  6  |     2      |    3    |   1    |
|  7  |     3      |    1    |   1    |
|  8  |     3      |    2    |   1    |
|  9  |     3      |    3    |   1    |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
```

During a selection process I retrieve two tempTables:

TempCountries:

```
+-----+------------+
|  id |  country   |
+-----+------------+
|  1  |     1      |
|  2  |     3      |
+-----+------------+
```

And TempProcesses:

```
+-----+------------+
|  id |  process   |
+-----+------------+
|  1  |     2      |
|  2  |     3      |
+-----+------------+
```

In a subquery I get all possible combinations of the values:

```
SELECT TempCountries.countryId, TempProcesses.processesId FROM TempCenterCountries,TempCenterProcesses
```

This returns:

```
+-----+------------+---------+
|  id |  country   | process |
+-----+------------+---------+
|  1  |     1      |    2    |
|  2  |     1      |    3    |
|  3  |     3      |    2    |
|  4  |     3      |    3    |
+-----+------------+---------+
```

During the selection process the user chooses a center for these combinations. Let’s say center = 7.
Now I need to update the center value in the Centers table where the combinations of the subquery are present.

So,

`UPDATE Centers SET center = 7 WHERE ?`

So I get:

```
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  id |  country   | process | center |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
|  1  |     1      |    1    |   1    |
|  2  |     1      |    2    |   7    |
|  3  |     1      |    3    |   7    |
|  4  |     2      |    1    |   1    |
|  5  |     2      |    2    |   1    |
|  6  |     2      |    3    |   1    |
|  7  |     3      |    1    |   1    |
|  8  |     3      |    2    |   7    |
|  9  |     3      |    3    |   7    |
+-----+------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: what is your db name?

Comment: A general solution for looking up tuples is `update centers set center = 7 where (country, process) in (select country, process from some_temp_table)`, but this syntax is not supported by all DBMS unfortunately. (Which is why you should tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using.) As in your case you get the tuples with a cross join, you can look up country and process independently as shown in Eponyme Web's and SNR's answers.

Comment: On a side note: Comma-separated joins were made redundant by explicit joins in the SQL standard of 1992! So your cross joining query should better be `SELECT TempCountries.countryId, TempProcesses.processesId FROM TempCenterCountries CROSS JOIN TempCenterProcesses`.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner thx for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have exact match of country as well as process before you run the update query. So, something like below query would help you achieve that. Basically update the column if there exists a record

```
WITH (SELECT TempCountries.countryId, TempProcesses.processesId
FROM TempCenterCountries,
 TempCenterProcesses) AS TempTables,
UPDATE Centers
SET center = 7
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM TempTables tmp
          WHERE country = tmp.countryId and process = tmp.processesId
         );
```

The idea is to update the record if both country and process matches with the one you have already fetched in temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this standard sql,

```
Update Centers
set center = 7
where country in (select country from TempCenterCountries)
   and process in (select process from TempCenterProcesses)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all sql implementations let you have a from clause when using update. Fortunately in your case since you're doing a Cartesian product to get all the combinations it implies that you don't have any constraints between the two values.

```
UPDATE  Centers
SET center = 7
WHERE   country IN (SELECT countryId FROM TempCountries)
AND process IN (SELECT processId FROM TempCenterProcesses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use update join -

For Sql Server

```
update c set SET center = 7 from Centers c
join
(SELECT TempCountries.countryId, TempProcesses.processesId FROM TempCenterCountries join TempCenterProcesses
)A on c.countryid=A.countryid and c.processesId=A.processId
```

For Mysql -

```
    update Centers c  
    join
    (SELECT TempCountries.countryId, TempProcesses.processesId FROM TempCenterCountries join TempCenterProcesses
    )A on c.countryid=A.countryid and c.processesId=A.processId
    set SET center = 7
```